# Validation and Evaluation Metric Issues in TensorFlow when Transfer Learning

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I have come across some odd behaviours when training CNNs with Tensorflow 2.0 and would appreciate any help in solving them. 
I am doing transfer learning (just training the classification head) using the pre-trained networks available in 'tensorflow.keras.applications' and have noticed the following:

1. For the first epoch, validation metrics are always zero, no matter what I do.
2. When training after the first epoch, the training metrics improve as you would expect, but the validation metrics essentially are random guesses, even when the EXACT same dataset is used as a training and a validation dataset. It is like it isn't using the model being trained to do its evaluation.

I have tried, VGG16, MobileNetV2, and ResNet50V2, and they all exhibit the same behaviours.

The configurations I am able to reproduce this on are:

- Ubuntu 18.04LTS, Nvidia RTX2080ti with driver version 430.50, CUDA10.0, TensorFlow-gpu==2.0.0
- MacBook Pro, TensorFlow==2.0.0 (cpu)

Both are running in Conda environments and I have installed TensorFlow with pip. I have put some sample code to show the essence of my workflow down below just in case I am doing anything obviously stupid.Any help would be very appreciated as I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

```
def parse_function(example_proto):
    image_feature_description = {
        'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
        'image_raw': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string)
    }
    parsed_example = tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, image_feature_description)
    image = tf.io.decode_image(
                            parsed_example['image_raw'], 
                            channels = 3, 
                            dtype = tf.float32, 
                            expand_animations = False
                            )
    image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
    label = tf.one_hot(parsed_example['label'], 24, dtype=tf.float32) 
    return (image, label)

def load_dataset(TFRecord_dir, record_name):
    record_files = tf.io.matching_files(os.path.join(TFRecord_dir, record_name + '.tfrecords-????'))
    shards = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(record_files)
    shards = shards.shuffle(tf.cast(tf.shape(record_files)[0], tf.int64))
    dataset = shards.map(map_func=parse_function)
    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=16, drop_remainder = True)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(16)
    return dataset



base_model = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50V2(
                                            input_shape=(224,224,3),
                                            weights='imagenet',
                                            include_top = False
                                            )
base_model.trainable = False

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
        base_model,
        tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
        tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(24, activation = 'softmax')
        ])

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(),
    loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
    metrics=[ 
            tf.keras.metrics.CategoricalAccuracy(),
            tf.keras.metrics.TopKCategoricalAccuracy(),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision(),
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall()
            ])

train_dataset = load_dataset(train_dir, 'train')

model.fit(train_dataset,
                verbose = 1,
                epochs= 5,
                validation_data = train_dataset)
model.evaluate(train_dataset)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I no longer have this problem since started using the docker images provided instead. There must have been something installed incorrectly but I don't know what.

Also, for anyone in the same position, I found out during debugging that if you are normalising your images using `image = (image/127.5) - 1` as in [transfer learning with pre-trained CNN turtorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/transfer_learning) change to `image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)` as it exhibits the same behaviour, even in the docker container, i.e.training metrics would improve, but the validation metrics would remain random on the same dataset used to train.

Answer (score 0):

> When training after the first epoch, the training metrics improve as
>   you would expect, but the validation metrics essentially are random
>   guesses, even when the EXACT same dataset is used as a training and a
>   validation dataset. It is like it isn't using the model being trained
>   to do its evaluation.

This means that your network is not able to learn everything and it just overfitting. Random guesses means that you have 1/n accuracy where n is the number of classes.

You may want to modify the learning_rate to a much lower value (1e-5) for start and then even unfreeze some of the lower layers(close to your GAP+Dropout+Dense).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. However, I get the problem though when the same dataset is used for both training and validation (I did this as a debugging stage). So even if it was overfitting to the training data I would expect the validation metrics to be around the training metric values.